# How to replace using for loop in range(len) by using enumerate

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a simple way to use `enumerate` instead of `for` loop with `range(len)`? For example, here I loop to replace all values of each element in subarrays by the index of its subarray.

```
list = []
for i in range(len(nparray)): 
    j = [i]*(len(nparray[i]))
    list.append(j)
```

My nparray is `np.array` with 6 subarrays, and each subarray has different size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` won't replace the use of `for`, just make it arguably nicer. You can use list comprehension however:
`[[i]*len(x) for i,x in enumerate(nparray)]`

And avoid using `list` as variable name since it's alrteady used as an builtin.

Comment: So here i is consecutive number from zero, and x is nparray? Why does it know i is consecutive number starting from zero? Thanks for comment about list.

Comment: That's just how `enumerate` works and is defined: it iterates over all elements (named `x` here) while also providing their indices (named `i` here). (`x` is not `nparray` but spans its elements.)

Answer (score 1):

to use enumerator, first you need to declare two target vars because enumerator return a tuple.

Using your example in a comprehension list, it could be like this:

```
listR = [[idx]*(len(val)) for idx,val in enumerate(multiarray)]
```

If you want to deep https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate

I hope this help you.

Regards